NGINX Relative Pathing Issue
I have a PHP application hosted in /var/www/acme for my acme.com server (name changed, of course). I want our internal teams to access it as http://acme.com:8080/acme and not http://acme.com:8080/ for just a little bit of extra security. I'm not worried about the SSL just yet -- we'll get that added soon when we move this into production from port 8080 to the regular SSL port. My application seems to work with the following configuration but it fails the relative pathing. For instance, if in my jQuery I reference $.post('login',{data:myForm},function(sResponse){console.log('RESPONSE:',sResponse);});, it thinks that login is login.php, which is correct, but then wants to load a /var/www/login.php instead of a /var/www/acme/login.php like I want. However, if I change my Javascript to reference 'login' as '/acme/login', then it works. So, what am I doing wrong in the following NGINX rules?
# Enable compression
# gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name acme.com www.acme.com;

    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
 
    location / {
        # Rule 1: If the path is a directory that exists, rewrite to the path + index.php
        if (-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ $1/index.php last;
        }

        # Rule 2: If the file exists, is not a directory, and is not a .php file, do not rewrite
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
        }
        if ($request_filename !~* \.php$) {
            set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
        }
        if ($rule_0 = "21") {
            break;
        }

        # Rule 3: If the file does not exist and is not a directory, add .php on the end
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.php last;
        }

        # Rule 4: If a file ends in .php and does exist, then load the file through the PHP handler
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }




    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


}

